# how can i remove every thing before ":" string in notepad++?

Tags: replace, notepad++

I have a file like this in notepad++

> n1:n1:n1
>   n1:n1:n2
>   n1:n1:n3

i want to delete everything before the first ":" including the ":" itself
and be like this

> n1:n1
>   n1:n2
>   n1:n3

and thanks.. 
hope i was clear enough in my explanation of my problem

Ken White : 
thanks but the problem is my file have over 10k lines and the first "n1" changes to "n2" after about 1000 lines
and then it become "o1" instead of "n1"
i want to delelte every thing before the first ":"

Comment: You know that you can select by column in notepad++ ?

Comment: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html

Answer (score 2):

Use Replace and use a regular expression to find any chars at the start of the line that are not a colon `:`, followed by a colon, and replace them with nothing

- Find what: `^([^:]+:)(.)`
- Replace with: `\2`
- Search Mode: Regular Expression

This actually answers your question and doesn't assume anything about what is before or after the first colon.

1. The first `^` indicates that the search must start at the beginning of a line
2. Parentheses are groupers and savers. They're not actually needed for this first bit, since you are just deleting the stuff before the colon, but this makes it parallel with Ken White's solution
3. Square brackets `[` `]` indicate which characters you want to look for
   a. The second `^` right after the first square bracket switches from chars you want to look for to chars you do **not** want to look for
   b. So `[^:]` means look for any char other than a colon
4. The plus `+` means look for 1 or more occurrences of this set of chars
   a. If some lines may start with a colon, and you still want to replace that colon, you'd want to look for **0** or more occurrences of non-colon chars at the start of a line
   b. To do that, replace the `+` with a `*`
5. Select the colon (so it will be deleted also)
6. Right Paren ends the first group
7. Left Paren starts the 2nd group
8. Dot `.` says look for any char. If you don't have this here, then it will delete everything before the first colon and then next set will be at the start of the line, so you'll delete too much. You could technically put a plus or star here, but you don't need it.
9. Right Paren ends the 2nd group
10. In the *Replace with* box, `\2` (that's a backslash or reverse solidus if you prefer) will take the contents of the 2nd group and replace everything it found with those contents

Here is the test input and output:

Input (stuck some tabs and spaces and other stuff in there for good measure)

```
n1:n1:n1
n1:n1:n2
n1:n1:n3
n2:n1:n3
n4:n7:n5

o1:n1:n1:m1:m1:l1:l7b:l1011
z99:

-- Here's some more data
o1:o2:o3:o4:o5
:o2:o3:o4:o5:o6
     o1:o1:o3:x37:n99
    n2:o1:o3:o44:z76
  n4:n7:n5:u72:j9:
```

Output

```
n1:n1
n1:n2
n1:n3
n1:n3
n7:n5
n1:n1:m1:m1:l1:l7b:l1011
z99:
o2:o3:o4:o5
:o2:o3:o4:o5:o6
o1:o3:x37:n99
o1:o3:o44:z76
n7:n5:u72:j9:
```

Notice it removed any line without a colon, which in some cases may be preferable. It also missed the two lines I threw in there with a colon at the beginning or end of the line.

If you wanted **to leave these blank lines in**, add an `\r\n` in the brackets in step 3 above (and again these are backslashes). Then it will look for any char that's not a colon **or end-of-line** (Step 3), followed by a colon (Step 5). Therefore, it only removes chars on the line with a colon. Change Find what to this string:

- Find what: `^([^:\r\n]+):(.)`

To catch the lines starting with a colon or with nothing after the first colon, change the plus to a star and add a question mark after the dot:

- Find what: `^([^:\r\n]*):(.?)`